# node does not serve images to remote client

Tags: node.js, http, express, vagrant

I am new to Node. I tried a hello world Express/Node application in which I am displaying a small text and some static images and some styling in a static css file. I am running my application on a hosted virtual machine using Vagrant on a computer I own.

The issue I am facing is that when I try the application from another remote computer in the same LAN, some images are not displayed. The corresponding GET requests are logged in Node with 200 status code but my browser is waiting forever for the answer. I tried Firefox, Safari and Chrome. The weird thing is that if I call the same application from the same computer hosting the virtual machine but outside the virtual machine then I can see the images.

Also if when I deployed the same application on a heroku account I could see all the images from the computer which could not display them.

So I really don't understand what could be wrong.

Please tell me if you faced a similar issue before.

Here is the code

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(router);

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

router.all('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Someone made a request!');
  next();
});

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
```

Here is the simple page layout. The two images are in the same folder.

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Express Routing
  body
    h1 Express Routing
    p The Definitive Guide
    img(src='/images/test.ico')
    img(src='/images/giraffe.jpg')
```

And here is the network trace when I call the application [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiBwk.png).

Eventually, I tried to use another sample application from an existing public git repository and had the same issue when I deployed it on my virtual machine (not all the static files are downloaded from a REMOTE machine whereas they all download if I call the application from the host machine).. As you can see 3 static files are pending download: 
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjMU0.png).

For your information when I use Rails instead of Node I don't have such issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was gone after I installed the latest ubuntu updates.

Thanks for your time!